# fgetcsv with text-delimiter '

Tags: php, excel, csv, fgetcsv

**I am trying to upload the data of an csv file into my database.**

---

The problem is that the excel file is far from 'normal':
The **line end character** is tabulator (**\t**)
and the **text-delimiter** is apastrophe (**'**).

---

Now, I am trying to get the following function to work. **With text-delimiter " it does work!**

```
public function uploadExcel()
{
    DB::table('members')->delete();

    $filename = Input::file('import_file')->getRealPath();

    $file = fopen($filename, "r");

    $count = 0;
    while (($emapDataUnescaped = fgetcsv($file, 10000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
        $emapData = self::addslashes_recursive($emapDataUnescaped);
        $count++;

        if($count>1) {
            DB::statement("INSERT INTO `members` (
                member_title,
                member_first_name,
                member_name_affix,
                member_last_name,
                member_private_address,
                member_private_zip_code,
                member_private_location,
                member_private_phone,
                member_private_mobile,
                member_private_fax,
                member_private_mail,
                member_business_position,
                member_business_name,
                member_business_address,
                member_business_zip_code,
                member_business_location,
                member_business_area_code,
                member_business_phone,
                member_business_fax,
                member_business_mobile,
                member_business_mail,
                member_join_date,
                extra
            ) VALUES (
                '$emapData[0]',
                '$emapData[1]',
                '$emapData[2]',
                '$emapData[3]',
                '$emapData[4]',
                '$emapData[5]',
                '$emapData[6]',
                '$emapData[7]',
                '$emapData[8]',
                '$emapData[9]',
                '$emapData[10]',
                '$emapData[11]',
                '$emapData[12]',
                '$emapData[13]',
                '$emapData[14]',
                '$emapData[15]',
                '$emapData[16]',
                '$emapData[17]',
                '$emapData[18]',
                '$emapData[19]',
                '$emapData[20]',
                '$emapData[21]',
                '$emapData[22]'
            )");
        }
    }
    return redirect('index');
}
```

**Add slashes_recursive function**

```
public function addslashes_recursive($data)
{
    if (is_array($data)) {
        return array_map('addslashes', $data);
    } else {
        return addslashes($data);
    }
}
```

---

I tried all kind of quotations marks etc. but I just cannot figure it out! I would be very thankful for any kind of help!

---

**UPDATE**
The file is not just on one line. Here are the options to display it correctly using LibreOffice:
[image]

Comment: Can you paste an example of the file? Are you sure that the *line-end* character is tab - as in, the entire file is on one line?

Comment: So add the enclosure argument as a single quote: `fgetcsv($file, 10000, "\t", "'")`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I updated my question. @iainn

Comment: Thank you! That is a good idea but the encolusure argument gives me an offset error further down the line, as there are some " in the file... @MarkBaker

Comment: Then we need to know what your actual file looks like, not simply how it is presented by the LibreOffice importer.... using `'` as the enclosure shouldn't trigger any errors with `"` in the file, only with other `'` characters, and then we need to know how they are escaped to add the extra escape argument

Comment: Thank you for your help! I cannot post this file here so I guess I will just have to do some more research about .csv files. But thank you for pointing me in the right direction! @MarkBaker

Comment: The only difference between the file which works and the that does not is that in the file, which does not work every line starts and ends with "  Does that information help at all? @MarkBaker

Comment: Are there any examples of `'` inside an enclosed string, e.g. names like `O'Brien`?

Comment: Then that `'` in `O'Brien` should be "escaped" somehow, to identify that it is part of the content, rather than a delimiter.... is there a "\" or similar escape character immediately before it in the file? e.g. `O\'Brien`

Comment: That information already helps me a lot! Thank you for that!! No, there is no escape character in the file, itself! However, I use the addslashes function on the file data (as shown in the code snippet in my question). I added that function to my question, in case it is relevant. @MarkBaker